# Remove listoftables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

%Preimenuje naslov Slike v Seznam slik, Tabele v Seznam tabel, Priloge v Seznam prilog:

\addto\captionsslovene{
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Seznam slik}
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}{}
 \renewcommand{\listappendicesname}{Seznam prilog}
}

% Oblikovanje naslovov poglavij (brez Chapter) -> St. poglavja in naslov poglavja
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{30\p@}%
  {\noindent\Huge\bf\thechapter \hspace*{0.5cm} \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
  \makeatother

%Priloge
\usepackage{appendix}
\addto\captionsslovene{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Priloga}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Priloge}
}

% Kazalo prilog:
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Priloge}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\renewcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}

% Seznam kratic
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\nomenclature[2]{#1 & #2 \\}

% \normalsize=12pt, \large=14pt
%\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc} % za Linux
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}  % za Windows
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

\end{document}
```

I want to remove `listtablename` from my paper. 
With this code it looks like this:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: But that will remove the `\listoftables` completely, not only in the ToC. And from the 'snippet' above it should not appear in the ToC at all!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see.  Not understanding Slovenian, I wasn't wholly clued into what I was looking at.  I will delete the comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I don't understand Slovenian neither.... I suspect a manual `\addcontentsline` or `tocbindind` usage

Comment: ok, but I don't know where "\listoftables" is.. It's not in the code, is it in the some other latex folder?

Comment: @wunderbar: The code above is neither compilable nor does it have `\listoftables` ... hard to answer it.

Comment: Where do the wrong `*` etc. characters come from? And in my comment above: I meant `tocbibind` of course ;-)

Comment: From "bold" and "italic", I will remove it

Comment: @wunderbar: Please add a minimal working example, i.e. with `\documentclass`,  preamble code and `\begin{document} some stuff \end{document}`.

Comment: The document does not compile yet -- `\begin{center}` is followed by `\end{document}`. And the cause of your 'problem' is `tocbibind`. What do you think `nottoc` does?

Comment: sorry I am new to latex, I'm doing my diploma and I got this script...and I don't know how to edit it to delete list of tables.

Comment: @wunderbar: Print the code 50 times on a4paper, roll the paper and hit the person who gave you this messy stuff on the head ;-)

Comment: hahaha :D Yes that's a good idea

Answer (score 1):

The preamble is a mess :-(

However, the main cause is `\usepackage{tocbibind}` -- that package is designed to add the contents and list of ... thingies to the ToC. Either say `\usepackage[nottoc,notlof, notlot}{tocbibind}` or don't use the package at all.

I am unsure about the `cp1250` options to the `inputenc` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,openany]{report}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}  % za Windows %Really???????
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{appendix}
\addto\captionsslovene{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Priloga}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Priloge}
}

% Kazalo prilog:

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Priloge}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\renewcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}

% Seznam kratic
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\nomenclature[2]{#1 & #2 \\}



%Preimenuje naslov Slike v Seznam slik, Tabele v Seznam tabel, Priloge v Seznam prilog:

\addto\captionsslovene{
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Seznam slik}
  % \renewcommand{\listtablename}{}% NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!XS
  \renewcommand{\listappendicesname}{Seznam prilog}
}

% Oblikovanje naslovov poglavij (brez Chapter) -> St. poglavja in naslov poglavja
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{30\p@}%
  {\noindent\Huge\bf\thechapter \hspace*{0.5cm} \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!

 \usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} - the list of table disappeared and with it also list of pictures? How do I get my pictures back :)?

Comment: @wunderbar: Or just don't use `tocbibind`, that's much easier ;-)

Comment: @wunderbar: The lists only vanish in the ToC

Comment: Yes, that's good, but I want my "list of pictures"- "seznam slik"- on the picture that I included, to remain...

Comment: Well, then remove `notlof` from the `tocbibind` usage

Comment: \usepackage[nottoc, notlot}

still no "list of pictures" :(

Comment: How can I get rid of the blank page where "list of tables" was?

Comment: @wunderbar: Well, with each comment you change the question. That's not how this site works.